# Best ranging way to discover beacon?

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon

In your opinion what is the best way to discover beacon, using proximity or only the array of beacons? 
I have a problem when i have two or more beacons near(1-2 meters) and can not get the right information of the beacon because it change quickly with the other neighbors beacon.
I work with swift 3 and ios 10.

Answer (score 1):

The distance readings on beacons are VERY sketchy.

Don't expect to get the beacon that is really nearest to be reported correctly as the nearest beacon unless there is a big difference in distances. (a beacon that's .5 meters away will report as "immediate" distance if the next beacon is 3+ meters away, but if one beacon is .4 meters away and the next one is .5, or 6 M and 7 M, they will be reported in unpredictable order. As Mady says, you should check the whole array of beacons, and not make any assumptions about relative ordering.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to use the proximity.
In the delegate you will find the array of the beacons, the first object is the nearest beacon, but in some case it's wrong too, so you should always **compare the found beacons into array** with their properties **(accuracy and rssi)** for finding the nearest beacon among the beacons array.

Comment: But the rssi and the accuracy arn't stable, How can I do that?

Comment: Yes because a small displacement is detected in term of location movement, Whenever delegates calls you need to check to find nearest beacon...